# I got jquery errors randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made website with jQuery and Javascript. I noticed that sometimes the JS file are not loading well. 
I got these errors in console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery.easing.1.3.js:37
>   jquery.anyslider.js:4
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery.anyslider.js:4
>   custom.js:3
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ custom.js:3
>   flytocart.js:1
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

If I refresh on page the errors are gone, and everything works properly. If I refresh again got errors. I got errors randomly.

My JS files all in the head section

```
<script async src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script async src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script async src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script async src="js/jquery.anyslider.js"></script>

<script>
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: ['Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,700,600,800,400:latin,latin-ext', 'Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic:latin,latin-ext', 'Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700:latin,latin-ext'] }
    };

    var cb = function () {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    };

    var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;

    if (raf) {
        raf(cb);
    } else {
        window.addEventListener('load', cb);
    }

</script>

<script async src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script async src="js/flytocart.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

What could be the reasons? How can I fix it?

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have added `async` to you script tags. Yes it will not block rendering of your page but it is not guaranteed to download those script in the same order in which you have added in page.

So try after removing `async` from script tags.

Comment: Great catch, moreover, its HTML5 tag and the browser support for it is Firefox 3.6+, IE 10+, Chrome 2+, Safari 5+, iOS 5+, Android 3+. No Opera support yet.