# Optimize CSS delivery (Pagespeed)

Tags: css, optimization, pagespeed

I am having a hard time trying to fix the "Optimize CSS delivery" recommendation on Google pagespeed. At this point this is the only thing I cannot fix.

1. I use a single minified css file for the whole site.The size of the css is 12.073 kb.
2. I don't make use of any `@import`in my css
3. I use CDN to deliver static files including css

[Website results](http://bit.ly/1G5ZaGA)

Any suggestions or fixes are most welcome

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30548159/148478

Comment: I think the problem is just the external ads included in the test, plus the CSS file that can be more optimized. If you download the `optimized_contents.zip` with the link on the bottom, you will see that google apply a little more optimization to your file. (spaces)... Now.. IMHO, going that far is good.. but don't have to keep you awake. Remember that all this are recommendations and some kind of guide for `good practice` but in the real world it's difficult to accomplish all. One last thing... I would not use a `CDN service` for a 12k file.

Comment: @Avinash i tried adding `async` or `defer` to the JS but its didn't fix the score especially for mobile,

Comment: @gmo with or without the space optimization.I use CDN for other files as well so why not css.I got many users in india and middle east so a CDN would improve their loading time since my server is in USA

Comment: Only for testing, try putting the CSS in a style tag (inline), but only to discard and compare speedtest results with: a) `inline`; b) `normal/internal load`; c) `cdn external load`. (BTW, be sure to wait google cache expire between tests)

Comment: Have you looked into adding the Page Speed module to your Apache or nginx server? It takes some time to configure but can automate the optimization process.